# Making one string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know this is simple but what is the best way to make my results into 1 single string not a tuple?

```
def lower_case(a):
    x=a.lower()
    y = ("This is now Lowercase:",x)
    return (y,x)

results = lower_case("LOWER CASE")
results

'This is now Lowercase:', 'lower case'
```

Thanks for the help on such a dumb question.

Comment: Why do you return a tuple if you don't want a tuple? Why do you define your own lower_case() method while the string objects provide the method on your own? What problem are you trying to solve???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you just want to concatenate the strings.

```
def lower_case(a):
    x=str(a).lower()
    y = "This is now Lowercase:" + x;
    return y;
```

Comment: This is pretty bad code. The `str(a)` is very unpythonic, one should use [duck typing](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-duck-typing) instead. It also introduces a nasty bug: If called with a unicode object that contains non-ASCII characters, this method will fail with a `UnicodeEncodeError`, because `str()` implicitly tries to encode `a` with the ASCII codec. Without it, the code would just work.

Answer (score 1):

Each an every solution proposed before is overly complicated in one way or another:

```
def lower_case(a):
    return "This is now lowercase: " + a.lower()
```

Does it in the simplest and most obvious way.

Comment: I tend to agree, except that using the overloaded `+` operator for string concatenation has significantly worse performance than using `str.join()`.

Comment: >>> timeit.timeit('"".join(("x", "y"))')
0.16582584381103516
>>> timeit.timeit('"x" + "y"')
0.035453081130981445

Comment: (Concatenation is slow if you have a long list of long strings. This is not the case here.)

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
def lower_case(a):
    return "This is now Lowercase: %s"%a.lower()
```

Or:

```
def lower_case(a):
    return "This is now lowercase: " + a.lower()
```

Or:

```
def lower_case(a):
    return "".join(["This is now Lowercase: ", a.lower()])
```

If you don't want a tuple, don't use a tuple. You can use [others methods to concatenation](http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/) too.

Answer (score 0):

```
def lower_case(a):
    return "".join(["This is now Lowercase: ", a.lower()])
```